# "Jumping" text from one page to the other

Tags: pdf, page, layout

In the pdf of a document I'm writing with the documentclass book I've seen that from one page to the other I have this "jump".

I tried to remove it with `\setlength\marginparwidth{0cm}` thinking it would have worked similarly to the indentation length but it didn't work.

Can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: `\documentclass[onesided...]{...}`

Comment: Your page layout seems to be "asymmetric", i.e.  have different margins for the even and odd pages. For further  help, we need to see a document example, which reproduce your problem. In general  consider @DonaldArseneau comment, i.e.  try `\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}`

Comment: @Zarko, indeed option "oneside" without a final "d".

Comment: @DonaldArseneau thank you, this worked